# Checking for JSON key without hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, json

I have a basic JSON key-value object, nothing nested. I don't see the point of using hasOwnProperty if the following does not throw an error in any browser. Can someone point out why this is safe, unsafe, or poor vs acceptable practice?

This is an example to set a default IF the input is blank or the property (key) doesn't exist.

without...

```
var config_arr = {key1:"val",key2:"val",key3:"val",default:"default val"};
var key = ""; //get value from user input, url param, route path, etc
var assign_val = (config_arr[key]?config_arr[key]:config_arr.default);
```

with...

```
var config_arr = {key1:"val",key2:"val",key3:"val",default:"default val"};
var key = ""; //get value from user input, url param, route path, etc
var assign_val = (config_arr.hasOwnProperty(key)?config_arr[key]:config_arr.default);
```

What's wrong with using the first technique and is either of these more efficient?

Comment: Where would you use `hasOwnProperty`, then? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but one pretty clean alternative to `hasOwnProperty()` is using `"key" in object`. It will return true/false depending on whether the key exists.

Using your code:

```
var config_arr = {key1:"val",key2:"val",key3:"val",default:"default val"};
var key = ""; //get value from user input, url param, route path, etc
var assign_val = (key in config_arr ? config_arr[key] : config_arr.default); 

//-- false
console.log("someKey" in config_arr);

//-- true
console.log("key1" in config_arr);

//-- "default val," since you passed an empty string as the key 
console.log(assign_val);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `in` operator is comparily slow, so, depends on how much intensive the code use it, `hasOwnProperty` may be or not the better solution

Comment: Yes, great point. I'd still opt for that. I'm also not completely confident it's as supported as `hasOwnProperty()` browsers.